# Getting form’s select list values before form’s submission

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I want to get the values from selected “select list option fields” in a form, before submit the form, and use them as variables in my web page.

For example:
I have the form bellow:

```
<form>
<select name="test">
<option value="111">Something</option>
<option value="222">Something</option>
<option value="333">Something</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I want to know if my web page user has selected the 111 or the 222 or the 333 value and after that to do something like that:

```
<%
If user selected the value "111" then 
Do something...
Else
Do something else...
End If
%>
```

Is there any possible way to do something like that before form’s submission?

After a long search I did, I learned that what I need can be done with JavaScript, but unfortunately I am completely ignorant with JavaScript. Could anyone guides me?

Comment: You can use the jQuery [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler to post the selected value to another .asp page that then returns data back to jQuery to do some other action with the form.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use form values as ASP variables without submitting them to the server because ASP runs on the server to do all it's stuff. JavaScript will run in the browser so can perform functions such as calculations without submitting the form to the server.

If you simply want to display the selected form options on the page then us can use JavaScript (or jQuery if you have that running on the page).
e.g.

```
<script>
 function showValue(s) {
  document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML = s;
 }
</script>
 <form>
<select name="test" onChange="showValue(this.value);">
<option value="111">Something 111</option>
<option value="222">Something 222</option>
<option value="333">Something 333</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="myid"></div>
```

If you want to process the selection in some way before submitting the form to either set another form field, or display some calculation you need to either write the calculation function in JavaScript or use AJAX (as suggested by ThatGuyInIT) to get another ASP page to do the processing for you and bring the results back to your page.

Comment: Your code is exactly what I need. The result of the script matches 100% to my needs. Now the only problem left to solve is this:
How can I convert this””” showValue (this.value)”””  in a variable (plain text) so I can use it the way I want it with vbscript. eg in a format that vbscript can understand and handle?? Because i don't want to display it in the screen. I just want to have it in a variable so to handle it later in my form..

Comment: You could use the JS function to add the value to a hidden form field that will be submitted along with the form. Remember, without using AJAX, vbscript (ASP) will not be able to do anything with the value until it is submitted back to the server.

Comment: OK. Now it’s clear to me. I will start searching for AJAX examples to leant how I can post it to the server so to have back my ready variable with the visitor selection. Thank you.

Comment: If the code is exactly what you need then you should mark this as the correct answer - click on the grey tick and it will change to green.